# Check if the generic type is a function type in Swift

Tags: swift, function, generics, types

I have defined a generic class as follows

```
class A<T:Any>{
   var value:T? 
}
```

I would like to know how I could limit T to be of a function type and can write code like value() in Class A.

```
let a = A<()->()>()
```

Comment: @Hamish it does, but he wants to force "Any" to be "()->()" if I'm not mistaking

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. If you were able to constrain `T` so that it can only be satisfied by function types (which you can't AFAIK) – then you wouldn't be able to say `value?()` inside your class, as you wouldn't know how many parameters `T` has, or what type they are, nor would you know the return type. If you just want `value` to accept `()->()` functions, then I don't see why you need make your class generic in the first place – just type `value` as `(()->())?`.

Comment: I also don't understand the question. The code you've written above is completely valid Swift (the `:Any` is redundant, but isn't hurting anything). What problem are you encountering?

Comment: i want say how to make  generic type T be a function type

Comment: @Hamish Your question is quite relevant. We have Any and AnyObject, and soon in 5.6 something to say 'not' Type. I could be needed to check a generics function or class is not misused with a closure or a function.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem, I ended up solving it like so:

First I defined a generic type representing a function which accepts a single parameter, and return value:

```swift
typealias Monad<A, R> = (A) -> (R)
```

I then defined my class to take a generic type parameter for the input type. In my case, every function passed was going to return void so I didn't need two type parameters.

```swift
class HoldsMyCallback<A> {
    let callback: Monad<A, Void>

    init(callback: @escaping Monad<A, Void>) {
        self.callback = callback
    }
}

...

let funcKoozie = HoldsMyCallback<Int> {
    print("keep my \($0) function cold")
}

funcKoozie.callback(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Referring to [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html):

> Generic code enables you to write flexible, reusable functions and
>   types that can work with **any type**, subject to requirements that you
>   define.

This is the main purpose of using Generics.

In your case, probably, this is the not right way of how to use them. You might want to make more simple:

```
typealias funcion = ()->()

class A {
    private var value:funcion?

    init(value: @escaping funcion) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func doSomething() {
        print("do something 01")

        if let iplementedValue = value {
            iplementedValue()
        }

        print("do something 02")
    }
}
```

Instantiation:

```
let aObject = A(value: {
    print("I want to this in the middle of my \"doSomething\"")
})

aObject.doSomething()
```

The output should looks like:

```
do somthing 01
I want to this in the middle of my "doSomething"
do somthing 02
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Generics code are made for Any or less. Some languages own ways to better control how generics are used. So the question of @ Hamish is interesting, and could introduce future evolutions of swift.